# How to say that something is intuitively right?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, expressions

Here the 'something' means a theory or a principle.

My sentence is

> While this principle can only be appropriately understood  in terms of
>   rigorous theorems (see below for some), it is in agreement with the
>   intuition that to fit a jump or a cusp we need fast oscillating terms.

But I am not so satisfied with the phrasing.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Or explain it better? This is really unclear.

Comment: Yes. I did. The whole sentence is there now.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Only the title of the question is understandable—but it's not enough to go on. The sentence is not only confusing, but I don't understand how it relates to the title of the question.

Comment: I feel that the wording is fine and that intuition is the correct word to use there.

Answer (score 1):

"Intuition" is defined as *the ability to understand something instinctively, **without the need for conscious reasoning***.

Given that you are talking about scientific theories and principles, I don't think the "intuition" you refer to is a mere 'feeling' or devoid of "conscious reasoning". I think you are trying to describe an intuition *based on experience*. As such, there might be a better word or phrase than "intuition".

If you really want to use "intuition", it should really *belong* to someone, or a group of people. Intuition is something that people possess, not something that is documented, so you should state whose intuition it is, rather than say "*the*" intuition:

> it is in agreement with **our** intuition that to fit a jump or a cusp we need fast oscillating terms.

Alternatively, if you agree that "intuition" might not be the most appropriate word, perhaps you could instead use "*theory*" or, even better "*working theory*". A working theory is based on known facts, not just guesswork or intuition. As a theory is normally documented, you can say "our theory" or "*the* theory" if you prefer, or if the theory is not yours.

Answer (score 0):

> While this principle can only be appropriately understood in terms of rigorous theorems (see below for some), it is intuitive that to fit a jump or a cusp we need fast oscillating terms.

Or something like **"it is intuitively obvious"**, depending on the circumstances.